# How can I get my search to return a "fail" message?

Tags: python

I basically have created a search function using a simple while loop, but i'd like to be able to have my programme return a "search failed" message if there is nothing that matches the search. How could I achieve this?

I basically have created a search function using a simple while loop, but i'd like to be able to have my programme return a "search failed" message if there is nothing that matches the search. How could I achieve this?

Here's the while loop if its helpful:

```
    while a < len(employee_list):
        if search.capitalize() == employee_list[a][2]:
            print (employee_list[a])
        a = a + 1
```

Comment: You can use a `for ... else ...` block instead.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple:

```
    found = False
    while a < len(employee_list):
        if search.capitalize() == employee_list[a][2]:
            print (employee_list[a])
            found = True
        a = a + 1
    if not found:
        print 'Search Failed'
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the write place for this, but thanks lot for this! I didn't realise it could be that straightforward.